# Don't fadeOut when hovering over parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the fadeIn of the menu working, and it stays open when I'm on the children of the ul, but when I hover back over the list item that activates the fadeIn it will close and then reopen.

I've tried a few things, but I can't get it to not close the menu when I'd rather it just stay open. Here's my js:

```
//Flyout Menu
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flyout = $('#directors-flyout');
    var second = $('.second');

    second.hover(function() {
        flyout.fadeIn();
        second.addClass('show');
    });

    flyout.hover(function() {
        $(this).show();
        $('.second .show').show('flyout');
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

    $('.first').hover(function() {
        flyout.fadeOut();
    });

    $('.third').hover(function() {
        flyout.fadeOut();
    });

    if($("#directors-flyout").is(':visible')) {
       second.hover(function() {
            flyout.show();
        });     
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you please post the markup, or a link to a fiddle?

Comment: couldn't you use CSS pseudo class `:hover` instead?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv3x8/6/ It's just the second li once the menu is open.

Comment: remove the hover out on "flyout.hover , function () { $(this).fadeOut(); }"

Comment: Thanks smiggle. That did it. http://jsfiddle.net/Gv3x8/10/